# Runtime defined global const variable in C++

Tags: c++, global-variables, constants, hpc, scientific-computing

I want to declare a global const variable that is defined at runtime. That is, I want to prompt the user for a value and assign it to a const global variable that I don't want to be modified during the execution of the program.

If I wanted a const variable in the `main` I could do

```
int tmp;
cin >> tmp;
const int var = tmp;
```

But if I want to use a global variable I can't because I have to declare it outside the `main`. For context, this is for high performance scientific computing. I want to define a set of physical constants that shouldn't change and that I need to access from anywhere. Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 3):

Write an init function for it:

```
int init() {
    int tmp;
    cin >> tmp;
    return tmp;
}
const int var = init();
```

Comment: I had to add inline keywords (added in C++ 17) to work.

Still the only answer I found useful (solved my problem) googling for hour about this problem, thanks.